# How can I add a pulse animation to a div in an array of divs, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-transitions

I have an array of divs that I create programmatically, like so:

```
// Create grid of pads dynamically, 16x16 in size
var padIdCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        var newPad = document.createElement("div");
        WinJS.Utilities.addClass(newPad, "pad");
        WinJS.Utilities.addClass(newPad, "row" + i);
        WinJS.Utilities.addClass(newPad, "col" + j);
        newPad.id = "pad" + padIdCount;
        document.getElementById("padContainer").appendChild(newPad);
        padIdCount++;
    }

    // Add a single line break after 16 pads
    var newLineBreak = document.createElement("br");
    document.getElementById("padContainer").appendChild(newLineBreak);
}
```

Pads are dark grey, but if a user taps on a pad it becomes an "active pad"

```
// Assign handler to pads, to toggle activation on click
var pads = document.querySelectorAll(".pad");
for (var padCount = 0; padCount < pads.length; padCount++) {
   pads[padCount].addEventListener("click", togglePadActivation, false);
}

function togglePadActivation(e) {
    // Get id of pad in question
    var padId = e.target.id;

    // Change pad from active to inactive and vice versa
    var clickedPad = document.getElementById(padId);
    WinJS.Utilities.toggleClass(clickedPad, "activePad");
}
```

Styles

```
    /* dark grey */
    .pad {
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        margin: 1px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: #363636;
        display: inline-table;
    }

    /* dark orange */
.activePad {
    background-color: orangered;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.playingPad {
    background-color: orangered;
    opacity: 0.6;
    /* workaround for pulse bug */
    animation: pulselightonanimation 3.2s ease-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes pulselightonanimation {
    0% {opacity: 1.0;}
    50% {opacity: 0.8;}
    100% {opacity: 0.6;}
}
```

Now that setup is complete, and event handlers are hooked up, the user can click a button that starts looping through all active pads (row 1 first, simultaneously, then row 2 simultaneously, and so on). To achieve this, I implemented a setTimeout.

```
// Run this method every 200ms
function playActiveNotes(rowCount) {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {

        // Reset after the last row, because we are looping indefinitely
        if (rowCount === 16) {
            rowCount = 0;
        }

        // Select all pads from the same row at once
        var currentRow = ".row" + rowCount;
        var currentRowPads = document.querySelectorAll(currentRow);

        // Cycle through each pad, animate and play it if active
        for (var padCount = 0; padCount < currentRowPads.length; padCount++) {

            // If the pad is active play the note
            if (WinJS.Utilities.hasClass(currentRowPads[padCount], "activePad")) {

                // Show the pulse animation
                WinJS.Utilities.addClass(currentRowPads[padCount], "playingPad");

                // TODO: Play short mp3 file here

                // Remove the animation class. This is where it fails
                //currentRowPads[padCount].addEventListener("animationend", callback(currentRowPads[padCount]), false);
                //currentRowPads[padCount].addEventListener("transitionend", callback(currentRowPads[padCount]), false);

                // If I use a nested setTimeout, this removeClass code never gets called. If I comment it out, I don't see the pulse, i.e. add + remove happens too quickly
                //setTimeout(function () {
                    if (padCount < 16)
                        WinJS.Utilities.removeClass(currentRowPads[padCount], "playingPad");
                //}, 1000);

            }
        }

        // Go to the next row
        rowCount++;

        // Then call self to setup a recursive loop.
        playActiveNotes(rowCount);
    }, 200);
}

function callback(element) {
    element.classList.remove('playingPad');
}
```

When the active pad is being played (I play a short mp3 file), I want it to pulse, i.e. become bright orange quickly (but not instantaneously), then fade back to the original dark orange. How can I achieve this? I tried using a playing pad class with css animation, and removing the class on transitionend/animation end, but that didn't work.

Use of WinJS is allowed in addition to Javascript, but no JQuery.

Comment: Please include your attempt(s) at making the pulse and tell us what went wrong. The code you posted seems fairly irrelevant the pulse animation.

Comment: What browser are you using? Maybe you need to include vendor prefixes on `animation` and `@keyframes` definitions? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Cross-Browser_Animations

Comment: Here's an [example with vendor prefixes](http://jsfiddle.net/Rj524/1/). It's working for me, you?

Comment: I'm using IE. I *think* I tried the -ms prefix before asking this question, but let me make absolutely certain and get back to you.

Comment: Incidentally, CSS3 animations are not supported in IE<10. http://caniuse.com/css-animation

Comment: Thanks showdev, my example also works for the infinite case. The problem I'm having is with removing the bright class after some time (does not depend on length of music). Please see http://jsfiddle.net/R5VjH/4/ for an example of what my code looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if somehow you can get a CSS animation going, that that would still be the best solution.

However, this is an alternative solution, using CSS transitions:

```
/* dark grey */
.pad {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #363636;
    display: inline-table;
}

/* dark orange */
.activePad {
    background-color: #B2371B;
    transition: background-color .5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .5s;
}

/* bright orange */
.brightPad {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: background-color .1s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .1s;
}
```

This should make it so that if you add the `.brightPad` class to a pad, that it goes quickly to bright orange (in .1s). As soon as you remove that class and set `.activePad` again, it should go slowly back to dark orange (.5s). You will have to set the `.brightPad` right on touch, and then remove it again using a timeout of 100ms or more.

Here is a quick JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R5VjH/1/

(sorry, used white instead of picking a nice bright orange)

Comment: Cool, but the OP wants it to "pulse" for the entire duration of a sound file. This only pulses once.

Comment: Good point. But if Javascript is the main system that handles the timing, then I think it's better to let that handle the individual pulses based on the audio files playing. In other experiments I've done before, Javascript's timeout and CSS's animations can easily get milliseconds out of sync. If after multiple loops JS and CSS could get very off... But of course testing it will show wether it's noticeable, I guess.

Comment: That makes sense. I wonder what the OP is planning to use to play sound and detect that sound is playing...

Comment: Just one pulse is perfect, thanks. The sound file is quick and short, like a drum beat or a music note. It is the removing of the class that I have struggled with, since it involves a nested setTimeout call and I cannot catch it in the debugger. Let me try this approach first, thanks for the fiddle

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The click to activate the pad is slow (takes 0.5 seconds instead of instantaneous), and once it turns to bright orange, it stays bright orange and does not return to dark orange. I have updated your JSFiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/R5VjH/4/

Comment: You were really close, only the nested timeout was being a bit annoying. I updated it and tried to explain what was going on in the comments on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R5VjH/5/ Hope it helps.